# Accessing application scoped cfc in another cfc

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

I have put a cfc in application scope in applicationstart(). Is there a way I can access this in another cfc.

```
 <cffunction name="method2" access="remote" returnType="Array" output="false">
    <cfinvoke component="application.cfc1" method="method1" returnVariable="result" />
<cfreturn result>
 </cffunction>
```

Thanks..

Comment: yes, that should do, but I think you'll like to write it this way more: `<cfset var result = application.cfc1.method1()>`  If it doesn't work for you, post the error / exception.

Comment: Thanks Henry for the help !!

Comment: Oops, @SamuelDealey is right, you need `##` to reference your `application.cfc1`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different ways to do that. Henry's recommendation works. If you want to use `cfinvoke`, you can do that too, but you need to understand how the tag works.

```
<cfinvoke component="application.cfc1" ... />
```

This syntax you used here where you're passing a **string** to the component attribute will look for the **file** "/application/cfc1.cfc" and attempt to invoke the method on that component. This is the rough equivalent of calling a static method from a Java class. It fails because you don't have a CFC file at that location.

If you already have a component instantiated then you need to pass the **variable** to the cfinvoke tag instead of a string literal. The simple change to make that work is to add the **hashes** around your variable name.

```
<cfinvoke component="#application.cfc1#" ... />
```

In general, this is how all ColdFusion tags work. If you put a value in an attribute without the hashes, you're giving ColdFusion a string literal value, not a variable. To provide a variable to the tag, you enclose your variable name in hashes.

This is surprisingly powerful at times and can also cause confusion if it's used in an unusual way. For example, I'm pretty sure this code would work, but should be avoided:

```
<cfset myvarname = "result" />
<cfinvoke returnVariable="#myvarname#" ... />
```

And then the result of your method call from the cfinvoke tag would be placed in the local variable named `RESULT`, because that's the value of the myvarname variable that was supplied to the returnVariable attribute.

EDIT: I wanted to add clarification from the comments below. When `cfinvoke` is called with a string-literal value for the component attribute (the first example above), Dan is correct, an instance of the component is created in order to call that method (there are no true static methods in ColdFusion). This might be undesirable (usually) if you're calling the method in a loop or otherwise calling it frequently, since you'd be creating a lot of whole objects that the ColdFusion server would then have to store in memory and soon garbage collect. Henry is also correct however, that if you pass an object reference with hashes (the second example above), the existing object is used instead of creating a new instance for each invoke, so you wouldn't have that performance problem.

Having said that, the primary reason I personally rarely use cfinvoke is because most of the time it's more keystrokes to do that, compared to calling the same method the way Henry recommended. Also, I'm not sure I've ever found a really compelling reason not to have an instantiated object, even if it's just a utility class that I load into my dependency injection framework (ColdSpring, LightWire, etc) so that my other objects can have access to it. There are a few edge cases though in which I've found having `cfinvokeargument` useful.

Comment: I suggest not using cfinvoke at all.  My understanding is that cfinvoke creates an object from the cfc and then runs the method.  In this case, the object is already there making cfinvoke less efficient than simply calling the method as per @Henry's comment to the question.

Comment: @DanBracuk no, cfinvoke will not instantiate a new object if a reference of an object is passed to `component` via `##`.

Comment: @DanBracuk That's a good point, although there's a bit of confusion about that. I edited my answer to add some clarification.